# Spring JPA cannot determine JdbcType

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

I'm trying to wire everything together: we have composite primary key in `EventDay`, and what i want is to map this key in `Event` so that we can access `EventDay` from there, and that's where problems begin.

Full error: `Could not determine recommended JdbcType for` me.offeex.inmyelement.entity.User`

Here's the code:

**EventDay.kt**

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "days")
@IdClass(EventDayId::class)
class EventDay {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    lateinit var user: User

    @Id
    val daysPassed: Long = LocalDate.now().toEpochDay()

    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumns(
        JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
        JoinColumn(name = "daysPassed", referencedColumnName = "daysPassed")
    )
    lateinit var events: Set<Event>

    lateinit var description: String
}

data class EventDayId(
    @Column(name = "user_id") private val user: User,
    private val daysPassed: Long
) : Serializable
```

**User.kt**

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class User(@Id val id: Long) {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    lateinit var days: Set<EventDay>
}
```

**Event.kt**

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long = 0

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    lateinit var group: EventGroup

    var rating: Byte = 0

    lateinit var icon: URL
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the problem was in `@Column(name = "user_id")` annotations.
Removing those in **EventDayId** and **EventDay** classes fixed the issue.